# T15 Haylou bluetooth headphone is detected but failed to pair

Tags: 20.04, kernel, bluetooth, headphones, headset

I'm using a **T15 Haylou** headset which works easily with my Android phone and also works without any problem with Windows 10.
But it's about a month I'm trying to connect it to my desktop PC which has **Ubuntu 20.04** installed. I tried everything you may guess and no working solution have been found.

I'll describe issue precisely in the following lines:

My bluetoothctl vesion is as follows:

```
$ bluetoothctl
Agent registered
[CHG] Controller 00:1A:7D:DA:71:15 Pairable: yes
[bluetooth]# version 
Version 5.53
```

My Headphones info is as follows:

```
[bluetooth]# info B0:BD:1B:0E:9C:CC
Device B0:BD:1B:0E:9C:CC (public)
    Name: Haylou-T15
    Alias: Haylou-T15
    Class: 0x00240418
    Icon: audio-card
    Paired: no
    Trusted: no
    Blocked: no
    Connected: no
    LegacyPairing: no
    ManufacturerData Key: 0xa212
    ManufacturerData Value:
  4d 2e fe 14 48 8e 93 d2 17 3c fd 02 30 03 bc 60  M...H....<..0..`
  f8 ef 4e 11 b9 b8 40 00 00 00 00                 ..N...@....     
[bluetooth]#
```

Now the problem is ***when I try to pair with this device, either via command-line or using Setting app, it lasts several seconds and then devices will not be paired without showing any information about what has been caused the problem***.

List of things already done:

1. I installed blueman and tried connecting via its GUI.
2. In blueman GUI, I also tried to connect to device without pairing as suggested by an askubuntu post, but didn't work.
3. I tried to pairing via bluetoothctl by commands: power on, scan on, trust, pair . but didn't worked.
4. I also tried to change Bluetooth adapter mode, as were suggested in another post, but again, didn't work. I think that there is no related post in Q/A websites that I've not tried since a month ago.

If you think that any other information will make problem more clear, inform me. I'll be thankful if anyone can help me solving this problem.

Comment: List the things you have tried. We can not guess what you have done.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same model of headphones. T15 Haylou

I have been struggling to connect it to my Ubuntu machine since I bought my headphones in 2021.

Here is how I accidentally fixed it:

1. I turned on Bluetooth on my Android phone
2. Connected my PC to my phone from the Gnome Bluetooth setting
3. Disconnected my PC from my phone from the Gnome Bluetooth setting
4. Connected to my headphones from the Gnome Bluetooth setting

Seems like it needed a small trigger to warm up! :)